# Text not overlapping image

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the text is not overlaying the image. I'm trying to get text to overlap the iamge with a colorful background. Does anyone know why it's not working?

```
    <body>
        <script>
        
            .container {
                position: relative;
                font-family: Arial;
                }
                
            .text-block {
                position: relative;
                bottom: 20px;
                left: 20px;
                padding-left: 20px;
                padding-right: 20px;
                background: rgb(113, 203, 0);
                background: rgba(113, 203, 0, 0.4);
                }
                
        </script>
        
        <div id="container">
            <img src="img1.png" alt="Execution" >
            <div id="text-block">
                <h1>Plan D</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum's plan is to remain ambiguous text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </body>
```

W3schools.com, typo's, etc.

Comment: Which part of the code is not working as intended? I'm not seeing anything that would make the text and image overlap. Also some images would help, to illustrate what you're seeing, and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @LawrenceWebDev [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_text_blocks) This is what I'm attempting but text just sits underneath the images.

Comment: Your code and the code you linked to are different though. Your `.text-block` CSS has `position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;`

Comment: You're right. I went ahead and changed that property to absolute but am still not seeing any change. I feel like I've compared the code to W3school's over a dozen separate times but I still can't find what else I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text block element has an `id` of `text-block`, instead of `class`. So the CSS selector `.text-block` isn't applying to it. Same with your container.

Your `<script>` tags should be `<style>` tags instead.

Comment: Solid correction, but the issue still persists. This hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Added additional corrections. You might want to just copy and paste the code from the example, and edit it, instead of coding by hand from scratch, since there seem to be many differences.

Comment: Changing it to Style instead of Script did it! Thank you very much.